# Create a vscode task to launch the debugger

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, task

Is it possible to create a task in VSCode to automatically launch the debugger? (in my specific case, GDB or LLDB debuggers)

If yes, do I need to call the debugger via command line to do so? (and just out of curiosity, if I don't -need- to, is it still possible to do it that way?)

Comment: use `launch.json` to specify debug configurations, or start the debugger with a task and create an attach launch config

Comment: @rioV8 This is completely unrelated to the question. I know how to use launch.json, I'm asking if it's possible to use tasks to launch the debugger directly, or to use tasks to launch.json configurations (while maintaining all debugger UI features, such as breakpoints, call stack...).

Comment: @rioV8 If you know how to set up a task that is able to start the debugger (both for launching the program or just for attaching to a process), then please share, but otherwise using launch.json by itself isn't really what I'm looking for.

Comment: if that would be possible why is there a `launch.json`

Comment: @rioV8 To make it easier? I don't know, and you also said in your first comment "start the debugger with a task", so I'm just confused now. Are you saying "it's not possible"? There is a lot of interpretation necessary in your messages.

Comment: the launch starts the debugger interface, if you start the debugger with a task or the launch (start or attach) is up to you. they will not implement something 2 ways, then you have 2 things to maintain for the same functionality

Comment: @rioV8 Ok but then, if you know how to start the debugger with a task, why not answer the question by showing how to do so? That is what I want to achieve.

Comment: because it is different for each and every debugger, the language server knows and creates the terminal command, you can copy that command to a task, VSC is a viewer using the debugger interface to talk to the debugger, the language server implements the interface

Comment: @rioV8 Could you then make an answer explaining how this works? Specifically, the architecture of how VSCode / "the language server" / the debugger manage to exchange data. It would also be nice to have an example with a specific debugger (preferably for a compiled .exe language), to explain the process: even if it is not the same for every debugger, you can point out where things can differ and what's native to the vscode communication architecture, or just debugger architecture in general. (this may seem obvious to you, but e.g. I did not even know "language servers" existed)

Comment: If you are looking for an easy way to launch a specific debug configuration, then maybe https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config can help.

Comment: It will probably make more sense if you add a `"preLaunchTask"` in your `launch.json` instead of the other way around? That way you can have a task ran before debugging

Comment: AFAIK You cannot launch a debugger as a task. You can however, run tasks before launching a debugger. For instance, I use `preLaunchTask` to run the compilation and building of a debuggable application, and then quickly launch its debugging. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score -1):

The official VSCode documentation provides all the information needed to manage tasks and debugging in the editor.

> Is it possible to create a task in VSCode to automatically launch the debugger?

Yes.

> do I need to call the debugger via command line to do so?

No.

> (and just out of curiosity, if I don't -need- to, is it still possible to do it that way?)

Yes. BTW I don't see how using an editor can make your command line unusable anymore.

see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug) for gdb/lldb specifically.

Comment: can you provide some more information rather that just linking an off site resource? if that link breaks you answer serves no value

Comment: The link I provide is an entire page dedicated to debug in vscode, first link in any research engine. The OP didn't take the time to just search the internet. Any more information I could provide will not be better than what's on this link.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Then come back when the link will break, or edit my answer or post your own. Do you really want me to copy past the entire VSCode user guide ?